# Jquery File Upload return file path as a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

1.I am trying to upload a file using ajax and jquery plugin i want to create a hyperlink that lets the user open the uploaded file My server side code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class NEW : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string pathh = @"../../upload";
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Uploads"];
        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            var filename = httpPostedFile.FileName;
            var fileSavePath = 
            Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload"), 
            filename);
            var retpath = fileSavePath;

            httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(pathh);
            newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, filename);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(newPath);
            Response.End();

        }



    }
}
```

2.The function called upon click is below it doesnt display anything if a return a string and make it a hyperlink.

```
        $(function () {
            $('#btnUpload').click(function () {

                var data = new FormData();
                var files = $("#fileupload").get(0).files;
                if (files.length > 0) {
                    data.append("Uploads", files[0]);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "NEW.aspx",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType:false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        alert("uploaded");

                    },
                    error: err

                });

                function err(data) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Return JSON and show it with jQuery - what is the actual problem?

Comment: If i do that i get an undefined object as an output i dont know why

Comment: Perhaps you need headers and well formed Json

Comment: my content type has to be false as i am uploading a fille

Comment: Not the response content type